# Set wallpaper from my site

Tags: android

I created a site with pictures in jquerymobile/photoswipe, and now i like possible set wallpaper from my site, from android app, i arrived at this point and I'm stuck, i'm new in android developer.

```
com.home.page ;

import android.os.Bundle ;
import android.app.Activity ;
import android.content.Intent ;
import android.view.KeyEvent ;
import android.view.Menu ;
import android.view.MenuInflater ;
import android.view.MenuItem ;
import android.webkit.WebView ;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient ;
import android.widget.LinearLayout ;
import android.widget.TextView ;


public class extends Activity { MainActivity

   / / Private WebView view ;


@ Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState ) ;
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main ) ;

        WebView view = ( WebView ) this.findViewById ( R.id.webView1 ) ;

        String url = " http://www.mysite.com " ;

      view.setWebViewClient (new WebViewClient () {
            @ Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading ( WebView view , String url ) {
                view.loadUrl ( url ) ;
                return false;
            }
        });
        view.getSettings ( ) . setJavaScriptEnabled (true) ;
        view.loadUrl ( url ) ;

        }
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu1 (Menu menu ) {

        getMenuInflater (). inflate ( R.menu.main , menu ) ;
        return true;
    }
@ Override
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode , KeyEvent event) {
    WebView view = ( WebView ) findViewById ( R.id.webView1 ) ;

    if (( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) && view.canGoBack ()) {
        view.goBack ();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown ( keyCode , event) ;

}

public void onCreate1 ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState ) ;
LinearLayout LinearLayout = new LinearLayout (this);
setContentView ( LinearLayout ) ;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu ) {
menu.add ( Menu.NONE , 1, 1 , " Share " ) ;
menu.add ( Menu.NONE , 2, 2 , " Save Image ");
menu.add ( Menu.NONE , 3, 3 , "Set Background ");

return true;
}
}
```

(I used OptionMenu Another best solution if there is welcome ) how do I associate the various commands and that when i click on the share i get a list of social , and save image set as background the current image.

Thanks.

Comment: Start reading a tutorial. Adding a 1 at the end of the default onCreateOptionsMenu to write your  own without compiler errors is a strong indicator that you have no idea what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Implement onOptionsItemSelected. There you have to check for the ID of the clicked element and do accordingly.

Example for the Wallpaper you use the [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) For the share intent use a [ShareIntent](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html).